# How to update an item in the array list

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a list.

This is my list code:

```
private static class Random{
    public  JsonObject randomData=null;
    public  Integer badgeNumber=null;

    private Random(JsonObject randomData,Integer badgeNumber) {
        this.randomData=randomData;
        this.badgeNumber=badgeNumber;
    }
}

private static class Randoms{
    private List<Random> randoms=null;

    public Randoms(List<Random> randoms) {
        this.randoms=randoms;
    }
    public Random get(int position) {
        return randoms.get(position);
    }
    public int size() {
        return randoms.size();
    }
}
```

I am adding data to list with this line:

```
randomsList.add(new Random(result.get(i).getAsJsonObject(),0));
```

But sometimes I have to update `badgeNumber` value.How can I update `badgeNumber` value of individual item ?

Answer (score 0):

To update value of individual position ,

```
int pos=0; //position you want to update
int newValue=100; // value you want to update
randomsList.get(pos).badgeNumber=newValue;
```

Comment: But I don't have an id

Comment: No need of id, just need pos where you want to update

Answer (score 0):

Add the following method to your Randoms class and call it to replace an object in the list with specified position:

```
public Random set(int position, Random newObjectWithNewBadgeNumber){
   return randoms.set(position,newObjectWithNewBadgeNumber);
}
```

Edit Random to the following:

```
    private static class Random{ 
     public int position; 
     public JsonObject randomData=null; 
     public Integer   badgeNumber=null; 
     private Random(int position, JsonObject randomData,Integer badgeNumber) {
                    this.position = position;
                    this.randomData=randomData; 
                    this.badgeNumber=badgeNumber;
                }
 }
```

Comment: How can I get position value ?

Comment: Then what member do you have from Random object to identify it instead of it's position?

Comment: How can I store positions of items ?

Comment: Add int id to Random class.

Comment: can you give an example ?

Comment: private static class Random{
    public int position; public  JsonObject randomData=null;
    public  Integer badgeNumber=null;

    private Random(int position, JsonObject randomData,Integer badgeNumber) {
this.position = position;        this.randomData=randomData;
        this.badgeNumber=badgeNumber;
    }
}